# Python3: List of list behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

code:

```
L = [False] * 2
R = [L] * 2
print(R)
[[False, False], [False, False]]
R[0][0] = True
print(R)
[[True, False], [True, False]]
```

I am trying to change one element but all elements in first column change. Is this the expected behavior?
Thanks